# SlateJS - Hovering toolbar example problem - selection & toolbar disappear randomly

Tags: reactjs, debugging, editor, slatejs

I'm trying to set up `Slate Hovering Toolbar` example in my React application. Here are example and codebase:

```js
https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/site/examples/hovering-toolbar.js
https://www.slatejs.org/examples/hovering-toolbar
```

I created new React component and c/p the code from example and here are problems:
 - hovering toolbar displays incorrectly (without icons for bold, italic, underline)
 - hovering toolbar doesn't appear immediately on selection, simnply I must try to select part of text 4-5 times repeatedly and then it appears
 - it also disappears randomly

Did someone face similar problems? I won't provide react app code here, because I used source code from example. I tried to contact creator Ian Taylor but couldn't find any contact info.

Answer (score 0):

This in the following cod sandbox you will find the right way of implementing hover toolbar. Also, you need to add your own icons [go to this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-elbakyan-vefe4?file=/src/HoveringMenuExample.jsx) and then go t HoveringMenuExample.jsx:118

Comment: Also, I am trying to implement [material ui toggle button group](https://material-ui.com/components/toggle-button/#toggle-buttons) in the toolbar. So, maybe you can help me with this?